# Disabling selecte option in drop down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`Hi,I am new to javascript and jquery. I am working on simple food  and chats ordering web application.

i have breakfast and quantity drop down box.when add button is clicked it creates dynamic table from selected option.how to disable selected option after clicking add button?

Comment: Hi, please show your code (+ your attempt at a solution) so people can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got the following html:

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="1">Foo</option>
  <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>

<button id="mybutton"> Click me </button>
```

Then you can use jQuery as such:

```
$(function(){
    $('#mybutton').click(function() {
        $('#myselect option:selected').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xw35w9od/